# All firebase projects returning 'Missing or insufficient permissions'

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, angularfire

Despite having changed my rules to the below, I am getting FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. Are there any other reasons firestore would return this error?

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Oddly, having checked other projects also live, I'm getting this error in ALL firebase projects, even ones I haven't changed. I haven't reached any quota limits and there's nothing out of the ordinary in the firebase console. I have also tried accessing from a VPN to change my IP to no avail.

Comment: yes it is driving me crazy... there must be some API issue, it started one hour ago... I had to re check all my production code...

Comment: Been in contact with Firebase support and they're getting back to me - although have just spotted this so clearly an issue on Google's end - https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/JH8hiSsfnSZHMdZqFTaC

Comment: thanks to this issue a found a decent refactor to be made in one of my collections...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an ongoing issue on Google's Firebase end:

https://status.firebase.google.com/
https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/JH8hiSsfnSZHMdZqFTaC

I don't think you can do anything except wait for Google's resolution.

Answer (score 0):

firebase have access issues for authenticated issues for Firestore.
now (15 Nov 2023   14:21 PST)

Authentication issues :[link](https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/JH8hiSsfnSZHMdZqFTaC)

Cloud Firestore issues : [link](https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/iRvJVnsbz8T47ySiy5Hg#PsdLE8rUi9SeXTKz6wWy)